# Can the coefficients of a linear kernel SVM be used to validate the feature importances of a decision tree?

Tags: svm, cart, validation

I'm currently using sklearn to fit a decision tree to a small data set (210 rows x 180 cols).  Interpretability is key as we'd like to be able to use the DT to make a white box model in order to tune process parameters.

My question is pretty simple : is there any reason to expect an SVM fit on the same data to reflect similar feature importances as the decision tree?

Answer (score 1):

When using a linear-kernel SVM, you should definitely not expect the fit to be comparable to a decision tree.

Simply put, a decision tree is able to find nonlinear characteristics of a dataset, whilst a linear-kernel SVM cannot. This is due to the different hypothesis in each model. The SVM tries to find *a* hyperplane to divide the space, while the decision tree uses *multiple* hyperplanes to divide the space.

Consider the following image: although not a perfect classification, you can see how the decision tree is able to find nonlinear features of the dataset, whilst the linear SVM cannot.

[image]

For the more robust SVM with RBF kernel, the division is made on an infinite-dimensional theoretical space, while the decision tree does not.